# Trigonometric equation $\sin(7x)+\sin(x)=\sin(5x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all real values of $x$ such that
> $4\sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(4x)=\sin(3x)$.

What I tried:

$2[2\sin(2x)\sin(x)]\sin(4x)=\sin(3x)$

$2[\cos(x)-\cos(3x)]\sin(4x)=\sin(3x)$

$[2\sin(4x)\cos(x)-2\sin(4x)\cos(3x)]=\sin(3x)$

$\sin(5x)+\sin(3x)-\sin(7x)-\sin(x)=\sin(3x)$

$\sin(7x)+\sin(x)=\sin(5x)$

$2\sin(4x)\cos(3x)=\sin(5x)$

Now I do not understand how do I solve it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: try using sum to product on $\sin(5 x) - \sin(7x)$.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin(7x)+\sin x=\sin (5x)$$ $$\sin(5x)-\sin(7x)=\sin x$$
$$2\sin\left(\frac{5x-7x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{5x+7x}{2}\right)=\sin x$$
$$2(-\sin x)\cos(6x)=\sin x$$ $$\cos(6x)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Taking inverse of cosine on both sides:

$$6x=2\pi n\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}\:\:\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ $$x=\frac{1}{9}(3\pi n\pm\pi)\:\:\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

**Edit**

I forgot the case of $\sin x=0$. Here the solution will be $$x=m\pi\:\:\forall m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: eyeballfrog's hint might have been sufficient + you forgot the case $\sin(x)=0$.